Automatically kill abandoned SSH sessions in CentOS 7
From time to time and for various reasons, PyTTY loses connection to SSH sessions on my CentOS 7 server (PuTTY is buggy, SSH server is buggy, router has been rebooted, connection is dropped, cable pulled out etc). These abandoned sessions are a burden on the server and consume resources. Could the CentOS 7 SSH server be configured to automatically terminate any SSH session after 24 hours, regardless of session purpose and state?
Why regardless of session purpose and status? Because in my opinion it can sometimes be difficult to distinguish between a normal session and an abandoned session.

Run at 4:00 am daily for user in $(w  | awk '/pts/{print $1}' | sort -u); do killall -u $user; done. Doesn't enforce the 24-hour requirement but how many sessions are still active at   4:00 am?

First of all, don't run CentOS7. It's EOL
Second, read man sshd_config:

ClientAliveCountMax
Sets the number of client alive messages which may be sent with-
out sshd(8) receiving any messages back from the client.  If this
threshold is reached while client alive messages are being sent,
sshd will disconnect the client, terminating the session.  It is
important to note that the use of client alive messages is very
different from TCPKeepAlive.  The client alive messages are sent
through the encrypted channel and therefore will not be spoofa-
ble.  The TCP keepalive option enabled by TCPKeepAlive is spoofa-
ble.  The client alive mechanism is valuable when the client or
server depend on knowing when a connection has become unrespon-
sive.


ClientAliveInterval
Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has
been received from the client, sshd(8) will send a message
through the encrypted channel to request a response from the
client.  The default is 0, indicating that these messages will
not be sent to the client.

Setting those to e.g. 3 and 600 respectively will terminate sessions after 3*600 second when the TCP session is dead.

First of all, don't run CentOS7. It's EOL. Everything becomes EOL with the time. Sorry, this is my own environment. I do not want to reinstall / reconfigure things completely only because they are EOL. My life is not for that. Thank you for the exact answer.

Everything becomes EOL. That's why IT systems has to be maintained. CentOS is not secure any more.

@Paul Yes, it is your own environment, just be aware that, if the system connects to the outside world, then any data on the system and possibly any data on systems in the same network are at risk. And I assume that you know you can upgrade CentOS7 to 8 without reinstalling. FInal comment - questions about unsupported systems are likely to be ignored since very few people are running them, the problems cannot be reproduced, and the issues may have been remediated in a current release.

@doneal24 CentOS 8 is actually out of support for far longer than CentOS7. And CentOS is atm a dead end. There's upgrade paths, but it's not CentOS anymore.

@vidarlo Yes, but CentOS 8 Stream is supported, although I would avoid it at all costs. You can however migrate a CentOS system to Rocky 8 or OEL 8 without reinstalling, both of which are well supported. CentOS Stream is not a dead end, it is just the beta release of REL.

@vidarlo Since I've ignored CentOS announcements completely after the policy change, I missed that CentOS 8 Stream is dead as of 6/2024. Surprising, what is RedHat using now for beta testing REL 8?
